# What is the purpose of `FutureOr`?

Tags: dart

Dart offers a [FutureOr](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) class, that allows writing:

```dart
FutureOr<int> future;

future = 42; // valid
future = Future.value(42); // also valid
```

I would assume that [FutureOr](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) would be useful to remove the unnecessary delay caused by the event loop if the value can be read synchronously.

But that doesn't seem to be the case, as showcased by:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  print('START');
  futureOrExample();
  print('END');
}

void futureOrExample() async {
  FutureOr<int> futureOr = 42;
  print('before await');
  await futureOr;
  print('end await');
}
```

which prints:

```
START
before await
END
end await
```

when I would expect:

```
START
before await
end await
END
```

In that case, why does [FutureOr](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) (or more generally `await 42`) work this way?

Similarly, what's the purpose of [FutureOr](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) in that situation since it produces the same result as [Future](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Future-class.html)?

I know that I could use [SynchronousFuture](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/SynchronousFuture-class.html) to achieve the desired result, but I'm just trying to understand what's the use of [FutureOr](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html).

Comment: to get the expected result you need to add await to futureOrExample(); inside the main() function

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The use of `FutureOr`, as introduced with Dart 2, is to allow you to provide either a value or a future at a point where the existing Dart 1 API allowed the same thing for convenience, only in a way that can be statically typed.

The canonical example is `Future.then`. The signature on `Future<T>` is `Future<R> then<R>(FutureOr<R> action(T value), {Function onError})`.

The idea is that you can have an action on the future's value which is either synchronous or asynchronous. Originally there was a `then` function which took a synchronous callback and a `chain` function which took an asynchronous callback, but that was highly annoying to work with, and in good Dart 1 style, the API was reduced to one `then` method which took a function returning `dynamic`, and then it checked whether it was a future or not.

In Dart 1 it was easy to allow you to return either a value or a future. Dart 2 was not as lenient, so the `FutureOr` type was introduced to allow the existing API to keep working. If we had written the API from scratch, we'd probably have done something else, but migrating the existing asynchronous code base to something completely different was not an option, so the `FutureOr` type was introduced as a type-level hack.

The `await` operation was also originally defined to work on any object, long before `FutureOr` existed. For consistency and smaller code, an `await e` where `e` evaluated to a non-future would wrap that value in a future and await that. It means that there is only one quick and reusable check on a value (is it a future, if not wrap it), and then the remaining code is the same. There is only one code-path. 
If the `await` worked synchronously on non-`Future` values, there would have to be a synchronous code path running through the `await`, as well as an asynchronous path waiting for a future. That would potentially double the code size, for example when compiling to JavaScript (or worse, if there were more `await`s in the same control flow, you could get exponential blow-up for a naive implementation). Even if you avoided that by just calling the continuation function synchronously, it would likely be confusing to some readers that an `await` would *not* introduce an asynchronous gap. A mistake around that can cause race conditions or things happening in the wrong order.

So, the original design, predating `FutureOr`, was to make all `await` operations actually wait.

The introduction of `FutureOr` did not change this reasoning, and even if it did, it would now be a breaking change to *not* wait in places where people expect their code to actually give time for other microtasks to run.

Comment: I was trying to find the sources of any `FutureOr` impl class to look how it is implemented but was not able to. Could you point out if this is possible?

Comment: It is not possible. The `FutureOr` *type* is not a *class*. `FutureOr<X>` is really a *union type* representing *either* a `Future<X>` *or* an `X` value. As such, it is a supertype of both of those types, and it's defined to be the *least* such supertype (it's defined to be a subtype of any type which is also a supertype of both `Future<X>` and `X`). There is no class correpsonding to the type, just as there is no no class corresponding to function types, `dynamic`, `void` or `Never`. They are just types.

Comment: Thanks, it really puzzled me. Now I see it's a special case wired into the type system.

Comment: So should new libraries use FutureOr or is this just a hang over from the dart1/dart 2 transition which should now be avoided?

Comment: Whether to use `FutureOr` depends on how you envision the API being used. Only ever use `FutureOr` contravariantly in your API (that is, *accept* a `FutureOr` as argument, or a function returning a `FutureOr` as argument), don't return a `FutureOr` to the user of your API. They'll then have to waste time figuring out whether it's a future or not. You can choose to accept that work, but don't push it onto others. If you would likely both have functions to accept a normal value and a future, you can combine it into one accepting a `FutureOr`. Otherwise, probably don't bother.

Answer (score 24):

The `await` keyword will always block the function execution.

Writing:

```dart
await 42
```

Is equivalent to:

```dart
await Future.value(42)
```

The reason being:

- This is how `await` works in Javascript
- it makes the behavior of `await` consistent.

---

Now, what's the purpose of `FutureOr` then?

`FutureOr` was never intended as a way to potentially make `await` synchronous.

Instead, it is an implementation detail of `Future`.

Without `FutureOr`, writing the following would not compile:

```dart
Future(() {
  return 42; // compile error, not a Future
});

Future<int> future;
future.then((value) {
  return value * 2; // compile error, not a Future
});
```

Instead, we would have to wrap all values in a `Future.value` like so:

```dart
Future<int> future;
future.then((value) {
  return Future.value(value * 2);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

for those who are still confused
I found good explanation https://itnext.io/what-is-futureor-in-dart-flutter-681091162c57 without diving into details
This piece of code could explain the target and real use cases of `FutureOr`

```
abstract class IDBService {
  FutureOr<String> fetch();
}

class FirebaseRemoteService extends IDBService {
  @override
  Future<String> fetch() async => await 'data';
}

class LocalHiveDbService extends IDBService {
  @override
  String fetch() => 'data';
}
```

so in implementations of `IDBService`

> the return type can be Future or String at the same time now!

Answer (score 3):

I needed to use `FutureOr` today. I wanted to call a function that *might* be asynchronously (not always).

```
String callbackOne() => "hello";

Future<String> callbackTwo() async => (await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),() => "This is a sentence"));
```

### Problem

- I can do `getLengthOfResult(callbackOne)`, but **not** `getLengthOfResult(callbackTwo)`. Conversely, if accept an async callback, I can't use the sync callback.
- [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0e12aa0f4745213a7efa5b5ff8c4934e)

```dart
Future<int> getLengthOfResult(String Function() callback) async {
  return callback().length;
}
```

### Solution

- [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=be619b223f20656ad5833402f93487ad)

```dart
Future<int> getLengthOfResult(FutureOr<String> Function() callback) async {
  // I can await on callbackOne, even though it returns a String.
  final result = await callback();
  return result.length;
}

main() {
  getLengthOfResult(callbackOne);
  getLengthOfResult(callbackTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the discussion.
Updating my Dart comprehension - pardon my C++/JS -ish approach.

Seems like this would be useful for singleton initiation.  Consider following:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class AClass {
  static String _info = '';
  
  static FutureOr<String> get info async {
    if (_info.isEmpty) {
      print('--> is empty...');
      _info = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), 
                                   () => "I'm alive!!");
    }
    else {
      print('--> not empty');
    }
    
    return _info;
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  String info = await AClass.info;
  print('Fist call: ' + info);
  
  info = await AClass.info;
  print('Second call: ' + info);
}
```

It works as expected - in either case, whether the `_info` member has been instantiated or not, the getter returns a valid string.

It works fine if I just use a `Future<String>` specifier in the getter, too.  The current implementation makes FutureOr seem mostly like a self-documentation exercise (can return a `Future<String>` or a `String`...)

But, even if await currently always locks the execution, a future update may allow it to work as expected, in which case using the `FutureOr` construct would anticipate updates.

(Aside: I imagine this example could be condensed using an `Optional` wrapping the `_info` member, but that's a different exercise...)

Comment: Note that using `async` forces you to return a Future, so `get info` is *always* a `Future<String>`, and never just a `String`. All that to say that `FutureOr` is entirely not needed here. 

(Also, if you want to shorten the code, use `String? _info` and `??=` instead of an if statement)