# How can I define a data type VoidCallback or AsyncCallback in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, types, callback, asynccallback

When creating a widget, I want to receive a function type parameter.

However, the type of this parameter can be VoidCallback or AsyncCallback.

Is there a way to apply these two types together? It is now declared dynamic.

This my code, see `onPress` field:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic onPress;
  final String text;
  final Color? textColor;
  const MyWidget ({Key? key, required this.onPress, required this.text, this.textColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: onPress,
        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: textColor ?? Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `FutureOr` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureOr`. [read more here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html)

here is an example of usage

```dart
import 'dart:async';

abstract class Barista {
  FutureOr<String> makeCoffee();
}

class SlowBarista implements Barista {
  Future<String> makeCoffee() async {
    return 'slow coffee';
  }
}

class FastBarista implements Barista {
 String makeCoffee() {
    return 'fast coffee';
  }
}
```

a great topic is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213196/what-is-the-purpose-of-futureor) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. I will read docs and discussion you referred to.

Comment: No problem, feel free to get back to me if you have more questions otherwise you may accept this answer too. thank you good luck